# Load an asset from outside a 'resources' folder

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to load "dynamic" assets (in particular, FBX files) that are located outside of a "Resources" folder so that the user can add/remove/modify files with no need to re-build the project.

To make those files easily accessible for the user in different kinds of devices (target platforms are desktop/android/ios), it seems reasonable to use either `Application.persistentDataPath` or `Application.streamingAssetsPath`.

Now the problem is: How do I load them (as proper Unity objects) ?

- This obviously can't be done via Resources.Load() as they are outside a "Resources" folder.
- Using WWW, retrieving the files should be easy and it could actually work for some types of files (e.g. textures, see http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html) but I cannot see a way to load something else.

The idea is that I'd like to be able to use those loaded objects like so:

`(GameObject) Instantiate(loadedObject, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);`

I would really appreciate your help (preferrably with a solution that does not require a "pro license").

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/loading-fbx-model-from-a-webserver.128344/)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I did not come across that thread :/ (I am not really pleased with the answer though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know two options that you can try to use in this case:

- Build an [asset bundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) for each dynamic asset you want to load, but this seems not really what you desire, because the user still have to use Unity3d to generate the asset bundle.
- Use an custom 3d model loader, like described in this [post](http://www.everyday3d.com/blog/index.php/2010/05/24/loading-3d-models-runtime-unity3d/), seems the best fit for your case.